Use PowerShell to open multiple Excel workbooks in parallel
I have a script that opens a set of Excel workbooks in a single Excel instance and updates connections and pivot caches.  The end user reports that they usually open all the workbooks and refresh connections in parallel (as opposed to "in series" as the script does).  It looks like parallel processing is possible with PowerShell but so far I'm unable to get Excel Workbooks to open using the script block and Start-Job method.  All that happens is that the Excel instance is launched and the job runs forever without completing and no workbooks open.
Best effort so far:
$filePath = "C:\testpath"

#Array: FileName, SaveAs
$files = @()
$files += , @("tst1.xlsx", $false)
$files += , @("tst2.xlsx", $false)

Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): Starting loop"
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$x1.Visible = $true

ForEach($file in $files) {
    
    # Define what each job does
    $ScriptBlock = {

        param([Object[]]$x1,
              [string]$filePath,
              [array]$file) 

        $wb = $x1.workbooks.Open("$filePath\$($file[0])")
            
        ForEach ($cache in $wb.PivotCaches()) {
            #Refresh this cache
            $cache.Refresh()
        }
    }
        
    # Execute the jobs in parallel
    Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $x1, 
                                         $filePath,
                                         $file
}

Get-Job
 
# Wait for it all to complete
While (Get-Job -State "Running") {
    # Pause for 10 seconds
    Start-Sleep 10
}
 
# Getting the information back from the jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job

Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss):Loop complete"

All of this works just fine without parallel processing:
$filePath = "C:\testpath"

#Array: FileName, SaveAs
$files = @()
$files += , @("tst1.xlsx", $false)
$files += , @("tst2.xlsx", $false)

Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): Starting loop"
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$x1.Visible = $true

ForEach($file in $files) {
    
    $wb = $x1.workbooks.Open("$filePath\$($file[0])")
            
    ForEach ($cache in $wb.PivotCaches()) {
        #Refresh this cache
        $cache.Refresh()
    }
}

Clues on how to get Excel to launch the workbook within the script block? I put a code break in on the $wb = $x1.workbooks.Open("$filePath\$($file[0])") and the code doesn't stop, it just runs forever.  This is the output returned:



Id
Name
PSJobTypeName
State
HasMoreData
Location
Command




1
Job1
BackgroundJob
Running
True
localhost
...


3
Job3
BackgroundJob
Running
True
localhost
...


1
Job1
BackgroundJob
Running
True
localhost
...


3
Job3
BackgroundJob
Running
True
localhost
...




I hope this is what your looking for:
#Define the Filepath
$filePath = "C:\testpath\"

#Define the Files
$files = @("tst1.xlsx", "tst2.xlsx")

#Clear the workbootPaths Array
$workbookPaths = @()

foreach ($file in $files) {
    #Create an PSobject that hold the filepath and the state (state is alway $false)
    $wbary = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Filepath = $filepath + $file
        State    = $false
    }
    #Add the PSObject to the $workbookpaths array
    $workbookPaths += $wbary
}

# Define the Job
$scriptBlock = {
    param(
        [string]$filePath,
        [string]$workbookPath
    )

    $x1 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $x1.Visible = $true

    $wb = $x1.Workbooks.Open($workbookPath)

    foreach ($cache in $wb.PivotCaches()) {
        $cache.Refresh()
    }
}

Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): Starting loop"

#Than start the job for each file
ForEach ($file in $workbookPaths) {        
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $filePath, $file.Filepath
}

Get-Job

# Wait for it all to complete
While (Get-Job -State "Running") {
    # Pause for 1 seconds
    Start-Sleep 1
}
 
# Getting the information back from the jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job

Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): Loop complete"


That actually opened the files for you?  The files don't open for me, I get an empty Excel window and that's it.  But also no, I need the files to stay open for end user review and action.

Oops, i misunderstood that and because i closed the workbooks at the end, i didn't noticed that. It seems like there might be an issue in the loop where the path isn't being correctly build, so Excel can't open this object. I have a workaround for the whole thing. You don't need to create the script block for every file in the loop.

That's an interesting approach, I went another way but this whole thing is turning out to be the wrong approach so I'm cutting bait.

Here's how I kind of solved it.  The issue is that the connection refresh could take a little time or a lot but PowerShell doesn't know how long to wait so it requires a chair/keyboard meatbag to complete the run.
#Establish important date variable strings
$evalDate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")

$filePath = "C:\testpath"

#Array: FileName, SaveAs (doesn't get used because don't know how long refresh takes)
$files = @()
$files += , @("tst1.xlsx", $false)
$files += , @("tst2.xlsx", $false)

Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): Starting loop"

ForEach($file in $files) {
    #Get last modification date (so can be skipped if already updated today)
    $dateModfd = (Get-Item "$filePath\$($file[0])").LastWriteTime.tostring("yyyyMMdd")

    #Check to see if the file to be updated hasn't yet been updated today
    if($dateModfd -lt $evalDate) {

        # Define what each job does
        $ScriptBlock = {

            param([string]$filePath,
                  [array]$file,
                  [string]$evalDate) 

            $x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
            $x1.Visible = $true
            
            $wb = $x1.workbooks.Open("$filePath\$($file[0])")
            
            Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): Refreshing connections for $($file[0])"
            ForEach ($objConnection in $wb.Connections) {
        
                #Refresh this connection
                $objConnection.Refresh()
                
                #If connection is still refreshing (query is running) then wait 2 seconds and check again
                #While ($wb.ODBCConnection.Refreshing) - doesn't work
                #{
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
                #}
            }
            
            ForEach ($cache in $wb.PivotCaches()) {
                #Refresh this cache
                $cache.Refresh()
            }

        }
        
        # Execute the jobs in parallel
        Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $filePath,
                                             $file,
                                             $evalDate
                          
        # Pause for 10 seconds so Excel can load
        Start-Sleep 10

    } else {
        Write-output "$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd.hh:mm:ss): $($file[0].ToString()) skipped because it was already modified today: $dateModfd. `n (Today: $evalDate)"
    }
}

